# How to Read a file from documents directory in iOS

Tags: ios

I need to search a file in documents directory of iOS but i don't know the extension of that file. How to search the file without extension. 
Below is the code if you know the filename.extension(abc.txt). How can i search for the same file with jsut filename(abc)

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, 
NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"abc.txt"];
NSString *content = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filePath     
encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL];
```

Comment: So, you're looking for a file named "abc" and you don't care what the extension is? If there were two files "abc.doc" and "abc.pdf", you want them both?

Answer (score 2):

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, 
NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSArray *directoryContent = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentsDirectory error:nil];
NSString *fileWithExt = nil;
for (NSString *file in directoryContent )
{
    if([file stringByDeletingPathExtension] isEqualsTo:@"abc"]
    {
       fileWithExt = file;
       break;
    }
}
```

**P.S. :** The `fileWithExt` will contain the first file with name `abc`