# iOS 8 To save file which is does not disappear on upgrade

Tags: nsfilemanager

My program now writes and reads ".plist" files using an absolute path. In iOS 8 after the upgrade is known as an absolute path changes. What code is in use, so as not to lose path to the file on upgrade.
Thank U

Answer (score 0):

I've found.
To save the file as normal using an absolute path.For example using the code

```
NSArray * paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains (NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
```

But you need to read a file like this

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,
                                                     NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSArray *directoryContent = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentsDirectory error:nil];
NSString *fileWithExt = nil;
for (NSString *file in directoryContent )
{
    if([file stringByDeletingPathExtension] isEqualsTo:@"abc"]
       {
           fileWithExt = file;
           break;
       }
}
```

I get code for read from
[How to Read a file from documents directory in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14097759/how-to-read-a-file-from-documents-directory-in-ios)

Thank U